# Можно ли переопределить занятый порт?

Tags: java, linux, debian

У меня есть игровой сервер, который является java-приложением. Этот сервер прослушивает порт 25565.
Клиенты подключаются к этому серверу, соединения могут длиться до нескольких часов.

Передо мной стала проблема деплоймента новых версий этого сервера. Чтобы запустить новую версию сервера, старый необходимо выключить. Но это приводит к закрытию соединений с клиентами. Даже в 4 часа утра имеется довольно много клиентов.

Я хотел бы запускать новую версию сервера, но при этом старую версию не выключать до тех пор, пока там имеются соединения клиентов. Но в таком случае новый сервер не включится, потому что он не сможет занять порт 25565, который все еще будет занимать старое приложение.

Можно ли как-то новому серверу переопределить порт 25565?
Чтобы новые соединения поступали на новый сервер, но при этом оставшиеся соединения с старым сервером не закрылись.

У меня сервера работают на debian 9.

Comment: Java так не умеет. Minecraft умеет рассылать предупреждение игрокам перед рестартом - может этого достаточно?  Если нет, то, вероятно, поможет port forwarding.  Например, https://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables

Comment: `может этого достаточно` после рестарта все равно половина онлайна не возвращается. по этому мне этого не достаточно. плюс если делать замену порта, можно будет делать деплоймент когда угодно, хоть посреди дня. если java невозможно, тогда решение на уровне OS тоже сгодится. port forwarding все равно потребует запуска нового сервера на новом порту. придется делать какуе-то сложную логику, чтобы автоматически выбирало каждый раз новый порт, на него делало прокидывание порта. с заменой одно и того же порта было бы проще, если это возможно

Comment: сказать бы как-то системе "больше не прослушивай этот порт", но как

Comment: Попробуйте закрыть тот сокет, на который вы делали `listen()` во всех процессах (это тот сокет, что  передается в `accept()`, в результете чего вы получаете новый connection)

Comment: docker-swarm, kubernetes и т.п.?

Comment: ¿А вариант обновлять без остановки сервера не рассматриваете? т.е. делать систему плагинов или выносить логику во внешний модуль, не трогая сам сервер, который держит соединения клиентов и выполняет какие-нибудь базовые функции

Comment: @user7860670 уже поздно, проект старый, архитектуру переделывать не вариант.

Comment: @avp `Попробуйте закрыть тот сокет` а как это сделать?

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук, в С/C++ для закрытия сокета надо выполнить системный вызов `close()` с дескриптором, полученным из вызова `socket()`. Наверное в Java тоже так. (не видя кода (и имея лишь смутные воспоминания о программировании на Java), что-то более конкретное посоветовать не могу)

Comment: `игровой сервер, который является java-приложением. Этот сервер прослушивает порт 25565` - это же Minecraft, не?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov да майнкрафт

Comment: @avp в С/C++ вызов `close()` не закрывает соединения с клиентами?

Comment: слушает порт tcp?

Comment: @eri да, порт слушает tcp

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук, соединение (в смысле обмена данными) с клиентом происходит по сокету, который вы получаете из accept. Так что, нет, закрытие сокета, который вы передавали  в  `listen()` (и который передаете в `accept()`), не обрывает уже установленные соединения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, что это возможно в java.

Если создать сервер, получить клиента и закрыть сервер, тогда соединение с клиентом останется открытым:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4004);
Socket clientSocket = server.accept();
server.close();
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println(clientSocket.isConnected());
```

Я проверил, по соединению `clientSocket` можно передавать данные.

Порт сервера освобождается после `server.close()`.

Answer (score 3):

Переносишь основной порт сервера на порт 25560

Фаерволом делаем проброс

```
iptables -t nat -A -p tcp --dport 25565 -j REDIRECT --to-port  25560
```

Второй сервер запускай на порту 25561

Добавляем проброс на новый порт и удаляем проброс на старый

```
iptables -t nat -A -p tcp --dport 25565 -j REDIRECT --to-port  25561
iptables -t nat -D -p tcp --dport 25565 -j REDIRECT --to-port  25560
```

Притом установленные соединения остаются там где были. Проблем не будет если клиент держит одно соединение на игру.

Comment: Скорее всего придется сделать так, спасибо